# Steven isn't at The Elite 4 to battle?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I went through Victory Road and talking to the people at the Elite Four they say Steven isn't there, so the league is closed.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Steven will be away from the League until you complete the [Delta Episode](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Delta_Episode).  When you exited your house after first defeating the League, you encountered a mysterious girl; follow her to complete the Episode.